# Returning a file content from Web Api using HTTP GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

A client will be issuing a GET request to our web api service, and we need to respond to that request with the specified file.

The file content will be as byte array like:

```
byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(retrievedAnnotation.DocumentBody);
```

**How do I respond to GET request with the above file content as a file?**

I've stubbed out a controller:

```
[Route("Note({noteGuid:guid})/attachment", Name = "GetAttachment")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<object> GetAttachment(Guid noteGuid)
{

    return new object();
}
```

**Instead of the new object, how do I return the fileContent to the GET request?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return file content from web api using below method

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAttachment(Guid noteGuid)
{
    byte[] content = Convert.FromBase64String(retrievedAnnotation.DocumentBody);
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(content);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "fileName.txt";
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");

    return response;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, i've changed the question just a bit, im wondering how do i respond with the attachment WITHOUT saving it locally, i want to just stream that byte arraay

Comment: also, i'm not going to know the file type, im only going to know the extension of the fiel

Comment: i got this response: {
  "FileContents": "eWVz",
  "ContentType": "application/octet-stream",
  "FileDownloadName": "blabsssg4rrxt.txt"
}

Comment: the filedownloadname is correct, however the filecontents should just be "yes"

Comment: didn't understand, can you please make me more clear ?

Comment: ` "FileContents": "eWVz"` this part ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125815/discussion-between-l-and-mostafiz).